# I have a Rails app and need to implement a "universal" or "skeleton key" password using AuthLogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I have the AuthLogic plugin installed in my RoR app. I not creating an app that needs to be high security. But I would like it if admins can log in as a particular user without having to know each and every one of their passwords.

I cannot find where AuthLogic actually validates the entered password upon login.

Anyone have any recommendations or advice as to the best method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation happens in the [Authlogic::Session::Password](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/password.rb) module.

If you wanted to override the default behavior, you would do the following:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  verify_password_method :my_verify_method
  private
    def my_verify_method
      if admin_user? # method that checks to see if the current user is an admin
        true
      else
        valid_password? # use default valid password method
      end
end
```

Comment: If you are logging in, can you still access the `current_user` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following. First you have to be logged in as an administrator, otherwise anybody could login if they would know the `magic word`.

Then inside your list of users you could show a link that redirects to an action that will log the currently logged in admin as that user. This way you can only show that link to the person s with the correct rights.

Logging in in code is actually pretty easy: just do `UserSession.create!(user)`, just the same as you test it, so that should work i assume.